# Is using “pretty damn spicy” to mean “actually very spicy” proper?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-meaning, sentence-usage

I often say something like:

> This soup is pretty damn spicy!

I am wondering now if this is actually proper grammar.

On [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pretty%20damn), it says the meaning of it is *“approximately”*, but when I use this term I don’t use it for “approximately”. Like the above example, I used it for saying “pretty spicy” or something like “actually pretty spicy”. I hope you get the way I use that term.

But still, I am wondering if that is proper or not.

I am also wondering if this is maybe too dirty language, so you can also say whether I should often say this or not.

Comment: Dirty language is subjective, but I would write it as "damned spicy" if I was trying to be grammatically correct, and I would consider "damn spicy" to be a more slang/short form of that.

Comment: @GlennWillen Dirty language? "pretty damn [adjective] is not dirty language. Certain slang has become very acceptable. 'pretty damn [adjective] is an example of this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Damn* works as an intensifier, similar to *very*. *Pretty* is much milder, and has a sense of "more than expected", "more than average". It actually works to soften *damn* in this sense, giving it a sense of "this is surprising!"

It's definitely informal language, and some people would be offended by the word *damn* anyway, but it's extremely common to hear, so I wouldn't call it "dirty language" really. It depends on the company you use it in!

A common thing nowadays is for people to soften their language intentionally, partly for fun and partly because it feels nicer and friendlier - not out of a sense of decorum. So consider using "this is pretty dang spicy!"

Comment: Yeah I agree. It's still a bit dirty.

Comment: I wouldn't call it _dirty_, as it doesn't have an obscene meaning, but don't use it with people you don't know well if you are trying to be polite.

Comment: I think 'damn' and 'damned' have lost most of their sting these days, and have a rather antique feel, at least in the UK, where church attendance is down to around 5%.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: It's dialectical to some extent. If you say "damn" in the American South, you will turn heads. Combine it with "God" and people will be quite annoyed with you.

Comment: A search for "damn good" reveals plenty of mainstream products using it. "damn good tacos" and so on.

Comment: @OwenReynolds - Not to mention the fine coffee in a certain TV series.

Comment: *The number of people using damn as an intensifier is too damn high.* [Know your meme](https://imgflip.com/memegenerator/Too-Damn-High)

Comment: @Kevin maybe in the most conservative rural parts, but no you will not turn heads with "damn" in a vast majority of "the south".  It's not the 50s anymore.

Answer (score 4):

What is "proper" is really opinion-based. Some people find "damn" offensive, while many do not.

What I can say is that it is not polite and would not be used in a formal setting. You might say it to people you know well, but probably wouldn't say it at a job interview.

Again, what is "dirty" is opinion-based. Many people divide curse words, or swear words, into the categories of just plain offensive (for example, scatological terms), and sexual (for example, the 'F' word, or slang terms for genitalia). It is the latter that people normally think of as 'dirty' language. 'Damn' originally had religious connotations - it means to condemn to hell - so it doesn't have any sexual connotations. If people do find it offensive it is likely because of the original religious meaning, although these days, it is just used as an *intensifier*, as it is in your example.

Comment: Yeah I shouldn't use this in formal chats, maybe with friends or just in an informal conversation I can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Some people find "damn" offensive, and some do not.

You should use in a conversation or not important situations, but not important situations. As I said, some people find damn offensive, so you shouldn't use it at a new person you met. Because you don't know the person will find "damn" offensive or not.

So this is not that offensive (as F-word), but (It's still a bit dirty) you should use this word carefully.

Comment: Yeah probably talking to friends it's okay, but now anywhere else

Comment: I once told a senior judge that I thought a certain politician was a 'damned fool' and he said "Mike, I'd use a considerably stronger adjective than that".